# Intent to play video is not working in android

Tags: android, android-intent, video

I am trying to open the default video play using intent in android. I searched and found a code at so may websites by that is not working for me. Below is the code I am using. please let me know where I am wrong.

```
intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
                    intent.setDataAndType(Uri.parse(http://198.74.53.248/overtribe/photos/115/post/282/1420275659d4ecm_video1.mp4), "video/*");
                    mContext.startActivity(intent);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try with VideoView:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
     // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    try {
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        String link="http://url_to_video.mp4";
        VideoView videoView = (VideoView) findViewById(R.id.VideoView); //add a videoview in xml
        MediaController mediaController = new MediaController(this);
        mediaController.setAnchorView(videoView);
        Uri video = Uri.parse(link);
        videoView.setMediaController(mediaController);
        videoView.setVideoURI(video);
        videoView.start();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        // TODO: handle exception
        Toast.makeText(this, "Error connecting", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
}
```

Comment: Ok, I will try with video view but can you please tell me why its not working with default video play. As I have to play it in default video play according to my application requirements

Comment: you may want to play without videoview: https://software.intel.com/en-us/blogs/2014/03/20/video-playing-with-android-media-player

Comment: yes, and the code I am using is same the code in the like you posted. Please let me know if I am doing anything wrong in my existing code

Comment: check the video if exists and like they did...try to set the values..and also what is the error you got? post the logcat.

Comment: the video is getting played on browser you can check by the video url in my code. it does not through any error. just try to load video by video player and then stops.